# Opentype features in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

Is it possible to use Opentype's features like ligatures in Libreoffice? if yes, how?

Because as far as I know, in Ubuntu and Linux in general, these features are available only for graphite(aka smart) fonts like `Linux Libertine G` (a free graphite font available [here](http://numbertext.org/linux/)). Opentype fonts have the same features but not accessible in Libreoffice. I'd explain more if requested.

---

[image: graphite vs. ordinary fonts in Libreoffice]

Please notice the differences in the snapshot. Ligatures are automatically being applied in graphite fonts. Word Arthur shows smallcaps feature.

Answer (score 4):

**First** way is about font features of Linux Libertine G and Linux Biolinum G include extended font names for LibreOffice:

`Linux Libertine G:smcp=1` for small caps

`Linux Libertine G:pnum=1&onum=1` for proportional & old style numbers

[Read more here](http://numbertext.org/linux/fontfeatures.pdf), and also you can use [Typography toolbar](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/typography-toolbar) for LibreOffice.

**Second** view for a problem is a letter "**G**" in the font name what have the meaning that this font is ready for use by **SIL Font Graphite Technology**.

[Read more about Graphite Font Extension for LibreOffice](http://thanlwinsoft.github.io/www.thanlwinsoft.org/GraphiteOOoExt/)

[image: Graphite Features]

[image]

Comment: WOW! Someone finally answered my question. Thanks you, good job. However, I searched all over the net and it tuned out that the opentype  features are not supported yet. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

LibreOffice has had support for Opentype features since version 5.3 released in February 2017. [This guide](http://www.scholarsfonts.net/Using_OT_in_LibreOffice_1-2.pdf) explains how to use them.

In brief, you need to turn on Opentype features by editing the four letter codes into font names. Click the font name and move the cursor to the end. Type a colon, then the four-letter code for the Opentype feature you want to enable, for example

```
Libertinus Serif:onum
```

To turn off a feature that is on by default, you can add `=0`, eg

```
Libertinus Serif:liga=0
```

To turn on multiple features:

```
Libertinus Serif:onum&pnum
```

See the guide for more information!

Comment: Is there a way to access this information inside LibreOffice?